# can we create our own cryptography system and use it with ethereum or hyperledger fabric frameworks?

Tags: blockchain, cryptography

i have a project where we have to build a fuzzy encryption for biomedical data like DNA and use it on blockchain for storage. So is it possible to create our own cryptography scheme on Ethereum and hyperledger ? if it's possible can you give me somewhere to start from. I'm totally new with blockchain implementations, i have just some knowledge in the theorical part. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In Russia, certified GOST cryptography has been built into both Ethereum (a project of the Fintech  Association Masterchain) and Hyperleger Fabric (Sberbank Blockchain Laboratory).

Comment: can you show me some tutorials on how to develop my own blockchain with my own cryptography scheme and built it ? i want tutorials from 0

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not participate in these projects as a developer, my team installed test and product nodes for these projects in our bank.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum, Hyperledger and other blockchains do not do fuzzy encryption, only deterministic encryption, so you are unlikely to want to use blockchain for your solution.